# Spring WebFlux and Thymeleaf form validation messages

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-webflux

I'm trying to learn webflux and thymeleaf but I'm stuck almost at the beginning. 
I was able to fetch data from form and validate it, but I'm unable to get error messages using ${#fields(...)} in thymeleaf.

Below you can find what I have currently:

Form:

```
     <form class="need-validation" th:action="@{/group/new}" th:object="${group}" method="post">
        <ul th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}">
            <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('name')}" th:text="${err}">Input is incorrect</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" th:text="#{groups.group.name}"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" th:value="*{name}" >
            </div>
        </div>
     </form>
```

And code that handles form:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> createGroup(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    return serverRequest.formData()
            .map(this::parseGroupData)
            .flatMap(group -> {
                Errors errors = validateGroup(group);
                if (errors.hasErrors()) {
                    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
                    model.put("group", group);
                    model.put("errors", errors.getAllErrors());
                    //model.put("fields", errors);
                    return ServerResponse.badRequest().render("/groups/group-create", model);
                }

                return ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(group);
            });
}

private FormGroup parseGroupData(MultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap) {
    Map<String, String> map = multiValueMap.toSingleValueMap();
    FormGroup formGroup = new FormGroup();

    formGroup.setName(map.get("name"));

    return formGroup;
}

private Errors validateGroup(FormGroup group) {
    Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(group, "group");
    groupValidator.validate(group, errors);

    return errors;
}
```

Validations looks to work correctly as there is present error on "name" field when i insert data which is incorrect.
How can I display errros using #fields object?
Or maybe in that case I have to write my own solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could trythis key for errors, it works for me.

```
if (errors.hasErrors()) {
    model.addAttribute(BindingResult.class.getName() + ".group", errors);
}
```

'group' is the thymeleaf object name.